# JW Player stopped working in Chrome, Safari, and IE9 but works in Firefox

Tags: mime-types, html5-audio, jwplayer

I've been using JW Player 5.7 to play audio mp3 files in a client's website for over year with no problem. My client just received a call that the audio was not playing. The audio is no longer playing in Chrome (v28), Safari (v5 and v6) and IE9. It works as it always has in Firefox (v23). I don't know when it stopped working, since both my client and I typically use Firefox. I don't know whether it's related to the browser or something else.

One thing that stands out is that using developer tools, it appears that the content-type header is correct in Firefox (audio/mpeg3) but is set to "text/html" for Chrome, Safari, and IE9.

Here's a link to a web page where you can see the issue:
http://www.thebuzzmusiclibrary.com/music/display_album/20

A couple of things that make this configuration a bit unique:

1. The jwplayer code is loaded dynamically, i.e. when the user clicks one of the "arrow" icons, the jwplayer code is loaded via javascript and starts playing since "autostart" is set to true.
2. Because the mp3 files are located above the directory root, the "file" parameter is actually a PHP function that actually downloads the file.

Here is the code that's dynamically loaded:

```
<div id="mediaplayer">This text will be replaced</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
"file": "' + file + '",
"controlbar": "bottom",
"width": "220",
"height": "24",
"provider": "sound",
"autostart": "true",
"bufferlength": "2",
"modes": [ {type: "flash", src: "/js/player-licensed-5.7.swf"}, {type: "html5"}, {type: "download"} ]
```

});

Here's the main part of the PHP script that downloads the mp3 file ($mime is 'audio/mpeg3')

```
header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Length: '.$info['size']);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');

while( ! feof($file))
{
    echo fread($file, 2048);
}

static::close_file($file, $area);

exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

One issue could be the fact that `audio/mpeg3` isn't a standard mime type. You should be using `audio/mpeg` according to [RFC 3003](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3003).

> The audio compression defined as layer I, layer II and layer III in the MPEG-1 and MPEG-2 standards is a popular method of compressing audio with a low quality loss. […] The mime type **audio/mpeg** defines a elementary byte stream containing MPEG frames according to MPEG-1 and MPEG-2, possibly interspersed with non MPEG data.

Answer (score 0):

I would update to 5.10 - http://www.longtailvideo.com/order/view, maybe some browser updates happened since 5.7 was out. That is the only reason I can think of for it suddenly not working.